# Unable to clear browser cache no matter what I do

Tags: javascript, firefox, localhost, browser-cache

I am working on a local project where I update the code inside a JavaScript file. I refer to the file using this line:

```
<script src="../annotate.js"></script>
```

1. I have tried pressing `Ctrl + F5`, `F5`, `Ctrl + Shift + F5`.
2. Disabled caching in the browser developer tools.
3. Cleared the entire brwoser cache using CCleaner.
4. Loaded the JS file URL directly in the browser. This does load the latest version once I do a hard refresh. However, if I reload the webpage which was referencing this file, it again loads the older stale version of the file.

This only seems to happen in Firefox.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Some basic isolation will help here:

Try a new profile in Firefox, it should create an entirely different cache.

Classic troubleshooting would be confirm you are loading the correct version of the file (via telnet, or another utility...) lets assume you are good here.

I don't know what `CCleaner` does, but long ago, Firefox did have weird cache-state problems that simply required a hard ("physical") removal of the entire collection of cache data.

(How do I know this? I was the ad-hoc/temporary lead-tester for "Cookies and Cache" for Mozilla, back in the day).

Most of these problems were resolved, but you seem to be describing the true edge-case where I would suggest isolating by profile.